# Как сделать анимацию появления блока в ангуляре?

Tags: css, angularjs

Как сделать чтобы когда нажимаем второй раз на кнопку, то блок плавно возвращался назад? jquery использовать нельзя, проект делается на ангуляре.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = false;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
    };
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  animation: my 200ms both linear;
}

@keyframes my {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

<button ng-click="toggle()">Show block</button>

<p class="fixed" ng-show="myVar">
   this is filter
  
</p>

</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, omnis earum accusamus dicta. Ipsa, consectetur, beatae illo impedit veniam esse ea fugiat corrupti consequuntur quasi minima nobis quidem dolorem ad.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а почему нельзя jQuery?

Comment: потому что использование jquery вместе с ангуляром это плохая практика

Comment: Лично я, не вижу в этом ничего плохого, если не смешивать функционал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного неверно с точки зрения использования ангуларовских классов, но суть ясна:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = false;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.myVar = !$scope.myVar;
    };
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  transform: none;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {
  display: block !important;
}

.fixed.ng-hide {
   transform: translate(-110%)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

<button ng-click="toggle()">Show block</button>

<p class="fixed" ng-show="myVar">
   this is filter
  
</p>

</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, omnis earum accusamus dicta. Ipsa, consectetur, beatae illo impedit veniam esse ea fugiat corrupti consequuntur quasi minima nobis quidem dolorem ad.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```